# Why System.out.println() not working in Netbeans 6.8?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-6.9, netbeans6.8

I am facing one problem in Netbeans 6.8, the output window of Netbeans not showing the output from project which i used as `system.out.println()`.

How to solve this issue with Netbeans 6.8?

Comment: mind posting an example of the nonworking println() statement?

Answer (score 0):

- Ensure that you are running the right project,  many a times we have
  multiple projects open and main project is some different project
- Ensure that the code block you want to get executed is reached by the
  Java Virtual Machine, it may happen that the code part if not reached
  due to some earlier condition
- Try posting example of your code here
  to get more specific answers

Answer (score 0):

that's because you have used lowercase 's' in the System.out.println()...
;)